# What is a good explanation for clipping, how it occurs and when it is likely to happen?

Tags: lighting, sensor, saturation, eclipse

Clipping causes a decrease in measured intensity when it's actually saturating. I haven't found a good source for explaining this, and when it should be looked out for, like under what expected conditions. If a detailed explanation can be given here, that'd be great. Since I can't find sources on it, links to sources would be good also.

Comment: Have you try here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, that's the type of eclipsing I'm trying to avoid getting info about when I search the topic.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I follow what you mean with this. Do you have some examples?

Comment: Are you talking about clipping? Please explain 'eclipsing' with respect to digital sensors.

Comment: Yes clipping, that has decreased from its normal maximum, due to eclipsing. I don't have an explanation, that's what I'm here for lol. No examples. I just know it's a thing, but there aren't many resources on it apparently.

Comment: If by "sources" you accept a small explanation I myself wrote some time ago: https://www.otake.com.mx/Apuntes/Imagen/EnviromentMaps/ The clipping is about the middle of the page... Dam. I need to reformat that page...

Comment: Are you talking about solarization?  Search for that term, and see if that describes the effect you're talking about.  I'm not sure about what might cause it in modern sensors, but what often happens is that an excess of light on the sensor interferes with the normal mechanisms it would have for reporting how much light it saw.